# Will appending records to a table using SSIS in Microsoft SQL Server Studio cause any downtime?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I have been tasked with performing a merge of data from one database to another.  Both databases will be located on the same server.  I am using SSIS within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to perform this transfer of records.  My question is, when I am performing this merge, will this cause any downtime for applications that rely on the database that the records are being transferred to?  If I have not provided enough information for a reliable answer, please feel free to ask for further clarification.

Thank you!

-Dave

Comment: How much data?  How many tables?  Why are you using SSIS instead of  just SQL statements?

Comment: I'd say there will be about 2,500 records. This is why I am using SSIS to transfer the data.  It is coming from one table and the merge process literally runs in a few seconds (I've tested the process on my local database).  I just want to be sure that I do not affect any applications that rely on the database I'm transferring to because I work in a real time communications environment and I'd hate to interrupt any services.

Comment: I'd forget SSIS and just run a SQL Statement, much simpler since they're in the same instance.  Blocking for a few seconds is usually trivial - unless your db requires instantaneous response time, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I am not too familiar with SQL and I've only tested the merge process using SSIS.  Could you point me in the right direction as to the syntax required to perform the transfer of my entire table using an SQL statement?

Comment: It'd just be `INSERT INTO Table2 (col1, col2) SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1`

Comment: Okay, I remember now that you mention that syntax.  I was initially going to perform the merge this way (using the INSERT statement).  The only problem is that I have around 60 columns that would need to be specified.  That is why I chose the SSIS approach.  It would take a while to set up this query and while I could still use this approach, it just seems that SSIS would be less time consuming.

Comment: Unless your users are traders beating against the database every picosecond, adding 2500 rows to a table shouldn't even be a blip on their radar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SSIS uses the serializable transaction isolation setting. (more detail -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

That setting will acquire locks as specified in the above article, and may indeed cause locking issues with applications that use the tables accessed by the package.

The duration of the locks and whether this is a problem in your environment are best determined via testing.

Comment: The reason I asked is because during normal business hours they do not want the merge performed if it will cause any interruption of service.  I guess I would be better off to suggest a time where downtime will not affect their service.  Better to be safe than sorry.  Thank you for your response and your information on this process.

Comment: In that case, I would definitely perform it after hours unless there is a business reason to do it real time.  If there is a reason, then it becomes a business decision as to which is more important, performance or current data.  You will need to test to determine the impact so they can make an informed decision.